# Node.js HTML response body

Tags: html, angularjs, node.js, http-post

I am using the below code to post some JSON data to a url and in response I am getting a HTML page.

```
var request = require('request');
request.post({
     url: "URL OF A WEBSITE",
     headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
     },
     body: {
       my_json_obj
     },
     json:true
}, function(error, response, body){
   console.log(error);
   console.log(JSON.stringify(response));
   console.log(body);
});
```

This code works fine I am getting a HTML page in the `body` tag.
I want to load that HTML page in the browser. How should I do that, I know this is a very basic question but I am very new to node.js someone please help me?

Comment: You'll need to serve that content using Express, or node.js' built in server library.  Right now, all you're doing is fetching it.

Comment: @zero298 so does that mean I'll have to create a server in node.js or something like that?
It would be helpful if you can give an example or share any link which has an example. Thanks.

Comment: The node documentation gives an example of how to create an http server: https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v4.x/api/http.html#http_class_http_clientrequest

Comment: The node implementation for an http server is the very manual way to do it.  Good to know how it works but the most common package for serving pages come from expressJs https://www.npmjs.com/package/express

Answer (score 0):

Follow the [Express "Hello World" example](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/hello-world.html) and use your request call in the route handler:

```
/*jslint node:true, esversion:6*/

"use strict";

const request = require("request"),
    express = require("express"),
    app = express();

let my_json_obj = {},
    URL_OF_WEBSITE = "http://www.google.com";

app.get("/", function (req, res) {
    request.post({
        url: URL_OF_WEBSITE,
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
        },
        body: {
            my_json_obj
        },
        json: true
    }, function (error, response, body) {
        if (error) {
            console.log(error);
            return res.sendStatus(404);
        }
        console.log(JSON.stringify(response));
        console.log(body);
        res.send(body);
    });
});

app.listen(3000, function () {
    console.log("Example app listening on port 3000!");
});
```

node.js does have its own way to make a server, but for the sake of brevity and ease I just recommend using Express.

Comment: res.send(body); this line loads the html in the broswer but the css is not loaded for that webpage.
Any idea why is this happening?

Comment: @Syn3sthete Open your browser debugging tools.  Do you get any errors?  Is the CSS from the same domain?  Probably not.  If you are trying to proxy a website, just use a proxy module.

Comment: yes you are right, the url is my localhost but the CSS reference error shows the url of the third party website. How do I add the proxy module to the above code?
Is it possible for you to edit it?

Comment: @Syn3sthete I'd recommend you just follow the documentation of any of the available modules such as [nodejitsu/node-http-proxy](https://github.com/nodejitsu/node-http-proxy)

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Express js? It would make things a lot easier when working with Node js apps.

Look into Express routing:
https://medium.com/javascript-scene/introduction-to-node-express-90c431f9e6fd

You can create an Express boilerplate in the terminal by using the command:

```
express yourappname
```

you can then put your html/css/js files inside the express-app -> 'public' folder that you just generated.

After that you create routes inside your app.js by doing something like:

```
// exampledomain.com/
// Loading the file index.html when user navigates to '/'
app.get('/', function(req, res){

    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/public/index.html'));

});

// or

// exampledomain.com/getFileURL
// POST request (from your ajax) to '/getFileURL'
// which will then load the about.html file into the browser
app.post('/getFileURL', function(req, res){

    // Do more JSON/data handling & Node js stuff here then
    // send something back

    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/public/about.html'));

});
```

There're many more useful functions with Express js, but I think Routing is what you need right now.

p.s. Very useful tools to look into when working with Node js:

- Postman (Testing ajax/express/Nodejs routes and responses)
- Nodemon (Starting Nodejs server automatically on save)